# Hide/disable adaptive cards in chat after user's selection

Tags: f#, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using microsoft bot framework v4 for our chat (in F#/C#).  We are using adaptive cards (version 1.2) to prompt the users for selection.  My question is how can we disable/hide the adaptive card after the user has made selection?  This is to prevent the user from scrolling back and making another selection from the same card.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Not much information here to work with.

Comment: This is client dependent. Will your users be accessing your bot via DirectLine, Teams, or another client?

Answer (score 1):

Please check following reference to update the card: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#net-example-1